# How to remove stroke outline when using brush tool?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How can I get rid of the black stroke outline when using my brush tool in Photoshop? I am using the current version. Is this a bug or I accidentally pressed something? This is the first time this happened to me.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just solved it myself. I didn't notice I am painting on a layer that has a stroke layer style.